# How to format _autoresponse email

Tags: forms, email, format, response, submit

i am using FormSubmit and i need to send autoresponse emails to the subscribers in my form, but the text is too long. How to format text in the value atributte?

I've tried use the text in the value atributte, but the text is not formatted how i need.